# Loop in two lists

Tags: python

I have these lists:

```
list1 = [3, 5, 2, 1, 9]
list2 = [6, 9, 1, 2, 4]
list3 = []
list4 = []
```

and I want to pass these formula:

```
x = a/b
y = 1/b
```

in which a is every value in list1 and b is every value in list2 and append the result of calculations into two empty lists - list3 and list4.

This is what I have but it's a disaster haha :(

```
u = 0
while u<len(list1):
    for a in list1:
        for b in list2:
            x = a/b
            y = 1/b
            u+=1
            list3.append(x,)
            list4.append(y,)
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the lists in parallel or over each combination of elements?

Comment: OK, then any of the answers below is correct :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a oneliner:

```
>>> list3,list4 = zip(*[(a/b,1/b) for a,b in zip(list1,list2)])
>>> list3
(0, 0, 2, 0, 2)
>>> list4
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

The output are `tuples`. But they can be easily converted to `list`.

Oh. It may be made even more memory efficient by using `generator expression` instead of `list comprehension`:

```
>>> zip(*((a/b,1/b) for a,b in zip(list1,list2)))
```

Comment: Nice trick. Its always better to avoid append considering it to be costly.

Comment: @Abhijit You are right. List appending is not very efficient (because of regularly needed memory allocations).

Comment: Thank you! I'm using this code and I have converted the tuples to lists. Thanks everyone who have answered too!

Answer (score 5):

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    x = a/b
    y = 1/b
    list3.append(x)
    list4.append(y)
```

This is assuming you meant you wanted to use the lists pair-wise.  If instead you meant you wanted every possible pairing of the lists, then:

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        x = a/b
        y = 1/b
        list3.append(x)
        list4.append(y)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for a,b in zip(list1,list2):
  x = a/b
  y = 1/b
```

?? something like this

Answer (score 4):

Just use the zip function in Python:

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    list3.append(a/b)
    list4.append(1/b)
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as the one given originally by @NedBatchelder

Comment: @Tadeck: This always happens when a question can be answered within seconds. No need to downvote since the answer is correct.

Comment: At a few seconds of interval I guess that's expected to have identical solutions when the problem has few solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
list3 = map((lambda x, y: x/y), list1, list2)
list4 = map(lambda x: 1/x), list2)
```

OR:

```
list3, list4 = zip(*map((lambda x, y: (x/y, 1/y)), list1, list2)
```

Comment: ICE BLUE, would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation? That would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. It would also give you the opportunity to point out how your answer is an improvement over the other, upvoted answers. I recommend to take the [tour] - for good luck.